# Double sigma notation case

Tags: notation

how to write this double sigma notation?

$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^i 5i $

which equals to -

$5\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{n(n+1)}{2} $

Thanks!

Comment: Well, you just wrote it?

Comment: Please check your variables.  For example, your final sum has $i$ as a variable, but the $i$ does not appear in the summation, so this would evaluate to $\frac{5n^2(n+1)}{2}$ (just $n$ copies of $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ added together).  Perhaps you meant $5\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i(i+1)}{2}$ instead?

Comment: You are certain that there was not meant to be a $j$ in the second summand, right? If there were a $j$ there, then the second summation would actually have intrinsic meaning, instead of just representing (as others have pointed out), $5i^2$

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^i5i=\sum_{i=1}^n5i^2=5\sum_{i=1}^ni^2
=\frac{5n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.
\end{align*}